# Auto Route for Flutter web

Tags: flutter, auto-route

I want to create a web like that:
I have a list menu on left and content right. When I click left item, right content will be replace by recent content.

Example like https://stackoverflow.com/tags
[image]

I think it is nested navigate and I follow by https://pub.dev/packages/auto_route#nested-navigation

But when navigate it animation all view. I don't want to like that.

Answer (score 0):

```
@AutoRouterConfig(replaceInRouteName: 'Page,Route')
class AppRouter extends _$AppRouter {
  @override
  List<AutoRoute> get routes => [
        /// routes go here
        AutoRoute(
          page: HomeRoute.page,
          path: '/',
          children: [
            AutoRoute(page: UserRoute.page, path: ''),
            // AutoRoute(page: UserRoute.page, path: 'user'),
            CustomRoute(
              page: UserRoute.page,
              path: 'user',
            ),
            CustomRoute(
              page: User2Route.page,
              path: 'user2',
            ),
          ],
        ),
        AutoRoute(page: UserRoute.page, path: '/user'),
      ];
}
```

I change AutoRoute -> CustomRoute it work.